# parsing string in java

Tags: java, performance, parsing

I have some problem in parsing one String as

```
String str="0|$5th std~~Pramod Deore|^97.0|^970.0|^1.02|^871.0600000000001|^S|^98.94|^5996.9400000000005|^12|^166|^|$7th std~~Vishal Chaudhary|^20.0|^220.0|^111.0|^-2000.0|^|^2220.0|^0.0|^110|^22222~Yogesh Gadage|^100.0|^3000.0|^10.0|^2000.0|^|^1000.0|^0.0|^16|^03~12|^111.0|^134532.0|^11.0|^133311.0|^B|^1221.0|^0.0|^45|^12~Chetan Patil|^200000.22|^2066002.2726|^-0.1500000549999395|^2096002.3166|^H|^-30000.044|^0.0|^20|^FEF-D~Sandeep Deshmukh|^-1.0|^-10.0|^0.0|^0.0|^|^0.0|^123.0|^29|^JPPWR~Yogita Gade|^25.0|^250.0|^100.25|^-2256.25|^X|^2506.25|^0.0|^30|^302|^|$";
```

Here in String I have 2 main records seperated by "~~"supppose 1. 5th std and 2. 7th std. Then in second record(i.e 7th std) there are 6 records seperated by "~".  Now I want to parse this response and store values of each individual records.

let take one record from 2nd one.

```
Sandeep Deshmukh|^-1.0|^-10.0|^0.0|^0.0|^|^0.0|^123.0|^29|^JPPWR
```

In short What I want is- I want to know say -"Sandeep Deshmukh" is from 7th Std. and 1.0 is his grade, 10.0 is his 2nd grade ......and JPPWR is his city short name

Then I must know it is from 2nd main record (i.e 7 th std) and also store all values of this record which is separated by "|^". How to do this. I had tried following code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ParseTest
{
String str="0|$5th std~~Pramod Deore|^97.0|^970.0|^1.02|^871.0600000000001|^S|^98.94|^5996.9400000000005|^12|^166|^|$7th std~~Vishal Chaudhary|^20.0|^220.0|^111.0|^-2000.0|^|^2220.0|^0.0|^110|^22222~Yogesh Gadage|^100.0|^3000.0|^10.0|^2000.0|^|^1000.0|^0.0|^16|^03~12|^111.0|^134532.0|^11.0|^133311.0|^B|^1221.0|^0.0|^45|^12~Chetan Patil|^200000.22|^2066002.2726|^-0.1500000549999395|^2096002.3166|^H|^-30000.044|^0.0|^20|^FEF-D~Sandeep Deshmukh|^-1.0|^-10.0|^0.0|^0.0|^|^0.0|^123.0|^29|^JPPWR~Yogita Gade|^25.0|^250.0|^100.25|^-2256.25|^X|^2506.25|^0.0|^30|^302|^|$";

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ParseTest pt = new ParseTest();
    pt.parse();
}

public void parse()
{

    System.out.println (str);

    ArrayList<String> stockrows = parseResponse(str,"|$");
                for (int i=1;i<stockrows.size();i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("iiii"+i+":::"+stockrows.get(i));

                    //parse with ~~

                    ArrayList<String> stockrows1 = parseResponse(str,"~~");

                    for (int j=0;j<stockrows1.size();j++)
                    {
                        System.out.println("jjjj"+j+"::::"+stockrows1.get(j));

                        //parse with ~
                        ArrayList<String> stockrows2 = parseResponse(str,"~");

                        for (int k=0;k<stockrows2.size();k++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("kkkkkk"+k+"::::"+stockrows2.get(k));
                        }
                    }


                }
}


public static ArrayList<String> parseResponse(String input, String delimeter) {
    ArrayList<String> parsed_strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (true) {
        int i = input.indexOf(delimeter);
        if (i >= 0) {
            String s = input.substring(0, i);
            parsed_strings.add(s.trim());
            input = input.substring(i + delimeter.length(), input.length());
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (parsed_strings.size() < 1) {
        parsed_strings.add(input);
    }
    return parsed_strings;
}
}
```

Any help will be apprecited. Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is not clear. Please add what you'd like to achieve, and what the pproblem with your code is. And **no, "it doesn't work" is not what we'd like to see...**

Comment: You are not parsing it! If you want to parse it please do your job with function not this, anyway you could read some class and deep understanding of encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

```
        String str="0|$5th std~~Pramod Deore|^97.0|^970.0|^1.02|^871.0600000000001|^S|^98.94|^5996.9400000000005|^12|^166|^|$7th std~~Vishal Chaudhary|^20.0|^220.0|^111.0|^-2000.0|^|^2220.0|^0.0|^110|^22222~Yogesh Gadage|^100.0|^3000.0|^10.0|^2000.0|^|^1000.0|^0.0|^16|^03~12|^111.0|^134532.0|^11.0|^133311.0|^B|^1221.0|^0.0|^45|^12~Chetan Patil|^200000.22|^2066002.2726|^-0.1500000549999395|^2096002.3166|^H|^-30000.044|^0.0|^20|^FEF-D~Sandeep Deshmukh|^-1.0|^-10.0|^0.0|^0.0|^|^0.0|^123.0|^29|^JPPWR~Yogita Gade|^25.0|^250.0|^100.25|^-2256.25|^X|^2506.25|^0.0|^30|^302|^|$";

        String a[] = str.split("~~|~");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But I also want to know that what is std of that particular records. i.e in 5th std only Pramod Deore, in 7th std there are 5 records i.e Vishal Chaudhary,Yogesh Gadage,Chetan Patil... and Yogita Gade